# pytest : module is not importing when run from pytest but works on plain python

Tags: python, pytest

This code works when run on interactive console :

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/path/to/mypkg")
>>> import mypkg.src.dbwrapper as dbw
```

But not like this :

```
$ cd /path/to/mypkg
$ python py -m pytest
mypkg/src/dbwrapper_queries.py:3: in <module>
    import mypkg.src.dbwrapper as ec
E   ImportError: No module named mypkg.src
```

I am running on `Python 2.7.14`

What might I be missing? It's the same import that fails when invoked via pytest but works when running just python and then import on the console.

Ed : I am not missing any `__init__.py` files - I do have them in every level.

Comment: yeap everywhere. let me update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you do an equivalent of `sys.path.append("/path/to/mypkg")` in `pytest`? Hint: define PYTHONPATH!

```
cd /path/to/mypkg
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/mypkg python py -m pytest
```